# wget specific directory with downloading whole path

Tags: wget

I try to download `data` using this command.

```
wget -r --no-parent http://myserver/username/data/
```

This leaves me with three folders on my server, namely: `myserver/username/data/`

How do I download only `data` without the whole path of folders?

Answer (score 0):

The manual says you could use the cut-dirs and no-host-directories options, as in

```
wget -r --no-parent -nH --cut-dirs=1 http://myserver/username/data/
```

and you could even use the --no-directories, or -nd.